# OSX Fatal error when compiling open source libraries

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, unix-ar

I get the following error on two different open source projects that I'm attempting to compile on OSX (Happens whether I target iOS or OSX).

The error isn't very helpful and doesn't appear to exist any more information about it.

`./configure` runs with no errors.

Any suggestions or thoughts?

> fatal error:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ar:
>   fatal error in
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib

Comment: What version of Xcode and what version of OS X are you running? Is it a beta version of Xcode/Mac OS?

Comment: Should be the latest public release for both. So Xcode 7.3.1 and OSX El Capitan.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling of Xcode?

Comment: I have not but several internal iOS projects build fine. I also just installed Xcode from the Store yesterday. This error also occurs when I do iOS builds of the same open source libraries.

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. Did you try installing Xcode-command line tools? And if you've run a beta or another version at the same time or you just re-installed it you should check in your terminal if you're still linked to the right Xcode.app 

Comment: Same issue on another developers mac running the same version. However, it worked on our "build mac" but there doesn't appear to be any differences...

Comment: Weird, was it the first time you ran the project on that other mac? (not the build mac), maybe it has something to do with the derived data?